# Google places API returning only 5 results

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google places API, It returns only top 5 search results. Is there any way to increase the count.

e.g. URL

I have searched for keyword "new"

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=new&types=%28regions%29&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

Comment: Downvoters please leave a comment before downvoting.

Comment: You should't give your "key"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the documentation:

> A JSON response contains two root elements:
>
> "status" contains metadata on the request. See Status Codes below.
>
> "predictions" contains an array of places, with information about the
>   place. **The Places API returns up to 5 results**.

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_responses

Comment: I have gone through the document and and found the same. Thanks.

Comment: @codeRider did you find any solution for this..? I just gone through that above mentioned link.. :(

Comment: @codeRider even I have a same quetion. Actually I used to get more than 5 results previously. But suddenly I am getting only 5 results returning by google.

Comment: You can retrieve all reviews if you're the business owner using Google My Business API. https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Answer (score 2):

Google specifies that they only give up to 5 results for place API.
You can check below image where google accepts this. [Google Place API Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results)
[image]